# Drawing Game Center like tableview cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-2d, game-center

***I've now added a bounty which will be awarded to anyone who can take the three images below and produce a working implementation of a UITableView that mimicks the look and feel of the one found in Game Center on the Games tab. The implementation must use a non-grouped tableview but demostrate each of the four cell variants (top, middle, bottom and single)***

Can anyone shed any light on how Apple achieve the **Game Center** tableview cells which appear on the **Games** tab?

I'm specifically referring to how they draw the border, and how they seem to get it to blend with the underlying green noisey texture.

I've tried drawing my own borders using Quartz 2D but cannot seem to get anywhere near the same quality, and I thought drawing with a color which had a low alpha component would achive the texture blending but this doesn't seem to be the case.

If anyone can shed any light, or even share any approriate code I would be incredibly greatful.

EDIT:

Something I've noticed is that the tableview doesn't conform to usual behaviour. In a normal grouped tableview the background is stationary and the cells scroll over it, but in Game Center (*and specifically the tableview I'm concerned with*) the background scrolls with the cells. This is leading me to believe that the tableview is not grouped at all, and this is but an illusion mixing Quartz 2D drawing and images.

EDIT:

So I've done a little poking around, and it does seem as though Apple a creating an illusion of a grouped tableview by using a standard tableviewcell, a seamless texture, a border texture and a cell mask. All this combined pulls off that illusion and supports my reasoning about why the background scrolls with the cells (*something I've so far been unable to replicate until now*).

Game Center cell background texture (*seamless*)

[image: Cell Background]

Game Center cell border texture

[image: Game Center cell border texture]

Game Center cell mask

[image: Game Center cell mask]

Now I've just got to figure out how they combine all these together to pull off this illusion. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The differences between the actual Game Center table and the solution @psycho suggested below which you can see is still some way off; the cell widths are too narrow, the border too thin and the corner radius too large.

[image: @psycho solution]

Comment: i've always been of the opinion that there's a gray scale image behind the core graphics drawing of transparent yellow and green, and likely direct text and image drawing as well, just a guess

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The cells are created using the three images above. They were taken directly from UIKit and are named in such a way that there cannot be any confusion about their purpose. I'm just trying to figure how to use/combine them to achieve the same effect.

Comment: cool, i was wondering if you had pulled them out - in that case, they could use the yellow either as a patterned color, or clip it to the shape they want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to answer exactly what you asked for because I used a grouped tableView, but when testing it seems to do the trick, and the background scrolls with the cells, as it can be seen in game center.

By the way, sorry, I don't use objective C but Monotouch and C#, but I know from experience it's not so hard to find bindings from one to the other when finding an interesting trick written in another language.

Well, stop babbling, here's the code.

```
public class test : UIScrollView {
    UIImage _borderTexture = null;
    int _paddingTop = 10;

    public test (RectangleF frame) : base (frame) {
        //setting the green background for the whole view
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(new UIImage("bg.png")); 
        //initializing texture for borders
        _borderTexture = new UIImage("bt.png");

        //adding some various-sized tables
        addTable(new string[] {"lonely cell"});
        addTable(new string[] {"top cell", "middle cell 1", "middle cell 2", "bottom cell"});
        addTable(new string[] {"this", "is", "a", "quite", "long", "table", "for", "an", "exemple"});

        //and then we adjust the scroll size to contents
        ContentSize = new SizeF(frame.Size.Width, _paddingTop);
    }

    void addTable(string[] contents) {
        // approximately keeping track of content's heights to adjust scrollView size
        // the table must be AT LEAST as high as its content to avoid its own scroll
        int approximativeHeight = contents.Length * 44 + 25;
        UITableView t = new UITableView(new RectangleF(10, _paddingTop, Frame.Width - 20, approximativeHeight), UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
        _paddingTop += approximativeHeight;

        //make the tableView's background invisible
        t.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0, 0);
        //setting the yellow texture for cell borders
        t.SeparatorColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(_borderTexture);
        //using our own data source to customize cells at creation
        t.DataSource = new testTVDataSource(contents);

        //finally, add the custom table to the scroll view
        AddSubview(t);
    }
}

public class testTVDataSource : UITableViewDataSource {     
    string[]    _contents = null;
    string      _cellID = "reuse";

    public testTVDataSource(string[] contents) {
        _contents = contents;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableView, int section) {
        return _contents.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (_cellID);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, _cellID);
            //make all backgrounds of the cell and its subviews to be invisible
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0, 0);
            cell.TextLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0, 0);
            //avoid the blue highlighting when selected
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        }
        //just some content for test
        cell.TextLabel.Text = _contents[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

So the main tweak resides in making your tableView transparent and high enough for it to not need scrolling, and to stick it into a scrollView which will scroll its background with its content (here, the tableViews.)

Comment: This is interesting; I'm away from my Mac at the moment so can't test, any chance you could post a screenshot showing how this implementation looks on the simulator or a device?

Comment: You wouldn't see anything about scrolling on a screenshot, here's a screencast ;). I took only part of a retina screen on simulator, this should be convenient for scrolling details.
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=0QPQ11HU
(Sorry for the MU link, my server seems to be experiencing some troubles...)

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this does indeed seem to mimic the scrolling behaviour, the style of the cells miss the mark somewhat. The border thickness in Game Center is much wider than that of yours, and also the corner radius is much smaller than yours. This is why I still believe they are using a mask (*see above*) and a non-grouped table.

Comment: Yep, I noticed your talks about a mask, but I must confess I have no idea about how to use it. And effectively, I hadn't see the thickness difference.. I'll try to get a look on that later.

Comment: I've added a side-by-side comparison image to the question above which highlights the differences.

Comment: Just a note : "the cell widths are too narrow" >>> That was the fact of the "Frame.Width - 20" in the declaration of table frames.

Answer (score 2):

They are removing all of the default drawing/borders and simply using custom cells with their own images.

Regarding your edit: This is incorrect. I've achieved that behavior too. <strike>, before, I don't recall exactly how I did it, I think I set the background image directly on the table view, not the view behind it.</strike> (See the code below.)

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I used to mimic the behaviour of cells "dragging" portions of the background with them:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tableView setRowHeight:65.0];

[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"metal_settings.png"]]];    

[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];

}
```

I've put this in a UITableViewController subclass and have inherited from that in several instances. If you look closely, the "color"/texture outside of the cells moves with the cells.

Comment: `I don't recall exactly how I did it, I think I set the background image directly on the table view, not the view behind it.` I'm afraid this is incorrect. I've currently setup a tableview this way and the cells scroll over the background rather than the background scrolling with the cells.

Comment: I'm of the opinion now that the tableview is not grouped, and Apple are using a seamless pattern as the background colour of the cells (*which is why the background appears to scroll*) whilst simulating the look of a grouped tableview cell.

Comment: I know from experience, @micpringle. I'll have to get the exact context.

Comment: Please do, as I have read through the documentation and studied all available properties (*both through code and in IB*) and cannot recreate the scrolling background using a grouped tableview.

Comment: Please see my latest edit above as reasoning behind why I still believe your comment to be incorrect.

Comment: @micpringle - I can't talk about iOS 5, but I've seen what I've seen. Nuff said. You could still be right.

Comment: @Moshe I have the iOS 5 beta 2 SDK running on another machine, so please do feel free to provide a code sample (*as it's still under NDA email is probably your best bet*). I'm more than intrigued as to how you can setup a UITableView in grouped mode and have the background scroll with the cells. Also, if this feature is iOS 5 only then the second part of your answer (*referring to my edit*) is invalid in this context.

Comment: @micpringle - Actually, I see the background moving with the cells in iOS 4.3.3 on iPad, with the latest public SDK.

Comment: @Moshe A UITableView set in **grouped** mode?

Comment: Oh, yes, it is in group mode. When creating the view, I simply initialize it with the grouped style.

Comment: This thing is, you're not setting the background of the UITableView to the pattern but instead are setting the background of the parent view which you specifically said you weren't: `I think I set the background image directly on the table view, not the view behind it.`

Comment: @Moshe Seems we got a little side-tracked with the most trivial part of my question. Do you have any thoughts on how to achieve what I've detailed in my latest edit?